# ¿Como hacer pruebas unitarias con phpUnit a los controladores de laravel?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Me queda mucho en duda hacer pruebas unitarias a los controladores que creo en laravel como por ejemplo: empleadoController, donde este tiene metodos como index, store, edit, Alguien sabe como debo realizar estas pruebas a los métodos del controlador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ver estas funciones que provee Laravel utilizas el comando al momento de crear tu controlador:

```
php artisan make:controller EmpleadoController --resource
```

y tu archivo de rutas

```
route::resource("EmpleadoController");
```

---

Respondiendo a tu comentario

En tu `composer.json` debes incluir:

```
// ...
"require-dev": {
"phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*" // <--------
},
// ...
```

despues ejecutas desde el terminal parado en tu proyecto

`Composer update`

desde consola ves que todo este bien

`vendor/bin/phpunit`

Despues en creas un archivo para pruebas en `App/prueba.php`

creamos una funcion

```
public function miapp()
{
       $response = $this->call('GET', 'miapp');
       $this->assertResponseOk();
       $this->assertEquals('App de prueba', $response->getContent());
}
```

Vuelves a ejecutar el comando:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

y en tu archivo de rutas:

```
Route::get('miapp', function(){
    return 'Esta es una prueba';
});
```

y de nuevo:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

de igual modo tenemos la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing) oficial de Laravel.

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing)

Comment: Si eso lo se hacer, el problema es como hacerle pruebas unitarias usando phpunit...

Comment: intentemos primero con lo de arriba que edite